# Template variable referencing custom method in models

Tags: django

I have a template `index.html`, which displays a list of email addresses. I have pre-specified authorized domains, and for all of these authorized domains, the address will be in bold.

This is my template --

```
{% for email in user_list %}

<p> 
{{email.email}} corresponds to this domain: 

    {% if email.valid_email %}
    <b>{{ email.email|domain}}</b>
    {% else %}
    {{ email.email|domain}}
    {% endif %}

</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is what I have in my models --

```
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def valid_email(self):
        verified = ['yahoo.com','gmail.com']
        domain = self.email.split('@')[1]
        return domain in verified
```

This works fine now, but my concern is about when I'll need to update the `models.py` and change the verified email list. Where would be a better place to hold this `valid_emails()` function, such that I can update it easily? And then how would I reference the function in the template (if different than current)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this list in your project `settings.py` file:

```
VERIFIED_TABLE_EMAILS = ('yahoo.com','gmail.com', )
```

using in model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def valid_email(self):
        domain = self.email.split('@')[1]
        return domain in settings.VERIFIED_TABLE_EMAILS
```

This way it's easy to update and you can access it from other places.

If this function is useful only for `Table` model, it's the right place (you are accessing the model fields). Otherwise, you can write a `custom filter` that validates any string against your email list.

filter:

```
def validate_email(value):
    domain = value.split('@')[1]
    return domain in settings.VERIFIED_TABLE_EMAILS
```

in template:

```
...
{{email.email}} corresponds to this domain: 
    {% if email|validate_email %}
    ...
```

See here for more informations on filters: [Custom template tags and filters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)